# Join two tables by two columns using a third mapping table

Tags: oracle

I have two tables with 3 columns that contains equivalent information, but for different environments. The two first columns are equivalent but different on both tables, like the same word on different languages. Each pair of the first two columns should be an unique identifier of the third column. Then I have a third table to make an equivalency between the two tables.

Let me explain it with an example.

Spanish table

```
Origin| Dest   | Code
mesa  | techo  | AA
mesa  | suelo  | BB
suelo | mesa   | CC
suelo | techo  | DD
```

English table

```
Origin| Dest  | Code
table | floor | XX
table | roof  | YY
floor | table | WW
floor | roof  | ZZ
```

Mapping table

```
Eng   | Spanish
table | mesa
floor | suelo
roof  | techo
```

Then the information that I want to get is:

```
AA | XX
BB | YY
CC | WW
DD | ZZ
```

As you can see, mesa+sobre should be mappet to table+over and then combine the code of that particular combination.
I have no clue about how to do this. I'm using an oracle database for simplicity, but I can process the data in any other way, so any suggestion is welcome.

Many thanks

**EDIT:**
I have changed the examples, because I just realized they were bad ones. In my real case, the two columns are of the same type, and the combination should take that in account.

Comment: You need to specify a mapping between adverbs (perhaps incorporating it into the existing mapping table) - otherwise, how should the db know about the correspondence between 'over'/'sobre' instead of 'over'/'debajo' ?

Comment: Dear @collapsar, you are right. I forgot to add the mapping. All maps are in the same table, because in the real case, all are of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could JOIN your spanish and english tables with the mapping table and get the equivalent of each word and then get the code:

```
WITH spanish AS (SELECT 'mesa' origin, 'techo' dest, 'AA' code FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                 SELECT 'mesa' origin, 'suelo' dest, 'BB' code FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                 SELECT 'suelo' origin, 'mesa' dest, 'CC' code FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                 SELECT 'suelo' origin, 'techo' dest, 'DD' code FROM DUAL),
english AS (SELECT 'table' origin, 'floor' dest, 'XX' code FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                 SELECT 'table' origin, 'roof' dest, 'YY' code FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                 SELECT 'floor' origin, 'table' dest, 'WW' code FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                 SELECT 'floor' origin, 'roof' dest, 'ZZ' code FROM DUAL),
map AS (SELECT 'table' english, 'mesa' spanish FROM DUAL
        UNION
        SELECT 'floor' english, 'suelo' spanish FROM DUAL 
        UNION
        SELECT 'roof' english, 'techo' spanish FROM DUAL)
SELECT spanish.origin, spanish.dest, english.origin, spanish.code, english.code
FROM spanish, english, map map1, map map2
WHERE spanish.origin = map1.spanish
AND spanish.dest = map2.spanish
AND english.origin = map1.english
AND english.dest = map2.english
```

Note that I changed the mapping table a bit. There were some words in English in the Spanish column. Also, I think the results you said were wrong. This is what I get:

```
DD ZZ
CC WW
BB XX
AA YY
```

**EDIT**: It's a bad habit of mine doing the joins like I did before. Using the proper syntax the query would be:

```
WITH (.....)
SELECT spanish.origin, spanish.dest, english.origin, spanish.code, english.code
FROM spanish JOIN map map1 ON spanish.origin = map1.spanish 
             JOIN map map2 ON spanish.dest = map2.spanish 
             JOIN english ON map1.english = english.origin AND map2.english = english.dest
```

Comment: Apart from the first part of the script that I did not understood in the first read (now I do ) this is the simplest solution in my opinion. I made some tests and the results seems to be correct. If you don't mind, pablomatico, could you explain me why are you using a multiple select instead of a join?

Comment: It actually is a JOIN. Sorry about that. It's the wrong way to do it and a bad habit I'm trying to get rid of. The spanish table is joined with map1 and map2 through `spanish.origin = map1.spanish` and `spanish.dest = map2.spanish`; and the english table as well. I'm not in my computer right now and can't rewrite the query but I will do it as soon as I can...

Comment: Hello @pablomatico, thank you for clarifying it. Actually your solution is working, that confuses me a bit. So the correct answer will look like the one proposed by @collapsar? Regards

Comment: @Danielo515 I just edited the answer to include the proper join syntax

Answer (score 0):

The double mapping on places and adverbs could be implemented as follows:

```
    select e.Code, s.Code
      from spaTable        s
inner join mapTableSpanish mts on s.Place = mts.Spanish
inner join engTable        e   on e.Place = mts.Eng
     where exists (
               select 1
                 from mapTableSpanish mts_sq
                where e.Adverb = mts_sq.Eng
                  and s.Adverb = mts_sq.Spanish
           )
         ;
```

Alternate Method:

```
    select e.Code, s.Code
      from spaTable        s
inner join mapTableSpanish mts_p on s.Place  = mts_p.Spanish
inner join mapTableSpanish mts_a on s.Adverb = mts_a.Spanish
inner join engTable        e     on ( 
                                           e.Place  = mts_p.Eng
                                       AND e.Adverb = mts_a.Eng
                                    )
         ;
```

**Note**

Dwelling on @MarcusH's table names here ( his solution, however, is wrong ).